# How to remove "Call requires API level" error?

Tags: android, eclipse

I get this error in Eclipse: Call requires API level 14 (current min is 8): android.app.ActionBar#setHomeButtonEnabled

This is code:

```
if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=14) {
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
}
```

In Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

How to remove this error?

Comment: Why does Android Studio give me this warning on `popRunReportUp()`, which >I< wrote, and whose version is none of Android Studio's business?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Add the line `@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)` above the method signature, where `Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH` evaluates to 14, the API version code for Ice Cream Sandwich.

Like so:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
public void yourMethod() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: @REACHUS Yes, `@TargetApi` just hushes the compiler about the error by telling it that we're aware and have handled it.

Answer (score 10):

Note: the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12631367/6287240) is outdated.

In `Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7` you don't need the `@TargetApi` annotation anymore.
It seems that the lint check is smarter now.

So this is enough:

```
public void yourMethod() {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right, but this method can't be used with constructor where "super" must be the first instruction called.