# how to set a Bitmap to background for a view Android API 10-18?

Tags: android, view, versioning

What I have is:

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

source:

```
View view = createViewFromWhatever();
Bitmap bitmap = loadSomethingAddMore();
```

Everywhere I have searched this is the accepted, suggested:

```
view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
```

But it is Deprecated in API 18. I am terrorised with framework bugs and miss documentations at OS level. I want to respect what they are saying and in case of crash "it is not my fault"

I can't even use the `new BitmapDrawable(bitmap)` and I  need `new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), bitmap)` instead. If I change my method to a recommended way: `setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), bitmap));`

It will mark as error with message:

> Call requires API level 16 (current min is 10):
>   android.widget.RelativeLayout#setBackground

As a solution I could check what version is running the user and do an if-else than I will have a code will with `if(isAndroidVersion10()) else if () ...`

Any solution acceptable solution?

If I escape from deprecation warnings via reflection I still will have the responsibility in case of crash, because I have release the code with deprecated method! -just the way how I call is different.

If I ignore that Lint, than it will crash at a low version api, tested.

Ofc  I want to support API 10 , so can't accept most of answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357344/call-requires-api-level-14-current-min-is-10)

Answer (score 20):

It was fast, got it from [here an acceptable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12631348/529543)

```
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
            setBackgroundV16Plus(mRootView, bitmap);
        }
        else{
            setBackgroundV16Minus(mRootView, bitmap);
        }



@TargetApi(16)
private void setBackgroundV16Plus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
    view.setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getActivity().getResources(), bitmap));

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setBackgroundV16Minus(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {  
    view.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
}
```

Man... a simple setBackground()...

Google started to copy non working things from iOS ( rotation, pushModal is very different in 4.3,5,6) horrible to develop multi version

Answer (score 1):

Just because something is deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work. From the [View source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/view/View.java), the definition of `setBackground` is (as of the latest version of Android):

```
public void setBackground(Drawable background) {
    //noinspection deprecation
    setBackgroundDrawable(background);
}
```

So as of this moment, you can certainly just use `setBackgroundDrawable` for all API levels. That isn't to say that checking on the SDK_INT isn't a good idea as future versions may change how `setBackground` works.

Comment: +1, I saw that in they source code. The problem is when the app will crash for some reason, when I can't demonstrate clearly it is user fault or OS bug. Than instant I am guilty because it is visible instant: I have used deprecated method...or can you explain to my users, clients "just because something is deprecated doesn't mean it doesn't work" sentence, when they have a crash? :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to this party but my friend i think the reasons for your crash are down to outOfMemoryExceptions not the setBackground method...make sure you are loading your bitmaps efficiently before setting them to a background. This could help  [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the boilerplate posted in the accepted answer, try this:

```
public static void setBitmapCompat(View view, Bitmap bitmap) {
    BitmapDrawable bd = new BitmapDrawable(view.getContext().getResources(), bitmap);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        view.setBackground(bd);
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundDrawable(bd);
    }
}
```