# Android - having troubles with extracting required data from JSON

Tags: android, json

In my app I have a local JSON file in the following format:

```
[
    {
        "iso": "AF",
        "tel": "93"
    },
    {
        "iso": "AL",
        "tel": "355"
    },
    {
        "iso": "DZ",
        "tel": "213"
    }
]
```

I'm getting the user's `iso` and according to the data in the JSON file need to extract the country code (named `tel` obviously).

The method that returns a string from the JSON file:

```
private String loadJson(){
        String json;
        try{
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("countries.json");
            int size = inputStream.available();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
            inputStream.read(buffer);
            inputStream.close();
            json = new String(buffer,"UTF-8");


        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return json;
    }
```

This gets the user's iso code:

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
        Log.i("Country Code: ", countryCode); //"AF" for example
```

And this is what i've done so far, which is obviously not working as I need:

```
try{ // doesnt work
            JSONArray arr;
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(loadJson());

            arr = new JSONArray(jsonObj);
            for(int i=0; i < arr.length() ; i++){
                JSONObject test = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                if(test.getString("iso")==countryCode)
               Log.d("TEL: ", test.getString("tel"));
            }
        }catch (JSONException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

On top of all, I'm receiving an warning `Call requires API level 19 (current min is 16): org.json.JSONArray` so I guess i need a workaround to extract the data i need (my solution doesnt work) and still support lower versions of Android.

Comment: the reason for the warning seem to be something else than what you have mentioned. AS org.json.JSONArray was added in API level 1. Here's a link to the documentation. 

developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html

Comment: My bad... Yes the warning is because the JSONArray(Object) constructor belongs to API level 19.

Answer (score 1):

The string you are returning from your load json method is a `JsonArray` not a `JsonObject`.

Change from

```
JSONArray arr;
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(loadJson());

        arr = new JSONArray(jsonObj);
```

To this

```
JSONArray arr;
            arr = new JSONArray(loadJson());
```

> For the Warning

Change the min sdk version in your manifest file like this

```
android:minSdkVersion="19"
```

or apply suppress warnings in your method `loadJson`

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631348/how-to-remove-call-requires-api-level-error)

Comment: This answer is correct. If you change the JSONArray constructor to take a String, the warning about the minSDK will also disappear. It's currently happening because the constructor you're using is the JSONArray(Object) constructor, which is from SDK 19 according to [the docs.](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 0):

In your menifest file replace

```
android:minSdkVersion="16"
```

with

```
android:minSdkVersion="19"
```

Comment: Cant, need to support lower versions of android as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your result comes from server in form of `jsonArray` but you try to convert in to `jsonObject`. Below is what you are trying to do :-

```
mJSONObject = new JSONObject(loadJson());
```

But you should to do this :-

```
mJSONArray = new JSONArray(loadJson());
```

And most important thing is `JSONArray(Object array)` was not introduced until **API level 19**.

[Read here](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray(java.lang.Object))

You can change your min **API** version in your `manifest` to be 19 or

you can convert your `Object array` to a `Collection array` like `ArrayList` and use the Collection array constructor of `JSONArray` which is available from   **API 1**.